# Twilio - Using taskrouter.js and reservation.conference() how to not beep and end conference

Tags: twilio, twilio-taskrouter

I am using task router to assign an incoming call task to a worker. When the worker gets the reservation I am starting a conference like this:

```
  worker.on 'reservation.created', (reservation) =>
    reservation.conference(null, idleSid, null, null, null, { "beep": "false", "EndConferenceOnExit": "true" })
```

There is not much documentation for how to handle a conference with taskrouter.js, but this seems to work to start the conference.

There are 2 problems I am having:

I can't stop the 'entering conference' beep to not play

When both the worker and participant exit the conference the conference is not actually ended and therefore not putting the worker into the after work activity state.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I've not worked with this yet, but here are some ideas.

The documentation shows that keys in the options have capitals, so I would change `"beep"` to `"Beep"`.

Have you tried using real booleans instead of strings for the options?

Umm. That's all I've got so far. If it still doesn't work, I'd recommend getting in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) as they can put you in touch with the TaskRouter team.